# Storing AnyObject in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've got an array that I'm trying to store timestamps into.

I'm testing stuff out with something like:

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {

    let post = ["MinutesLeft" : (FIRServerValue.timestamp())]
    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId().setValue(post)

}
```

Then I'm trying to call it back and fill an array with some of those timestamps:

```
  DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrderedByChild("MinutesLeft").queryStartingAtValue(Int(cutoff)).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

     let post = snapshot.value!["MinutesLeft"]

        print("POST \(post)" )

        self.postsArray.append(post)
            print(self.postsArray)
        } else {
            print("Didn't work")
        }

    })
```

Then I'm running a timer that's meant to clear out certain posts:

```
func removeExpiredItems() {
    let cutoff = UInt64(1000 * floor(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) - 10*60*1000)

    while (self.postsArray.count > 0 && self.postsArray[0] < cutoff) {
        // remove first item, because it expired
        self.postsArray.removeAtIndex(0)
        print(postsArray.count)
    }

}
```

My issues are :

I don't know what kind of array to have here. It's telling me that a timestamp is an AnyObject, but when I go to make an array of anyobjects I get a straight up Xcode internal error crash...so I guess that's a no-go.

I can translate it all to strings and just store it like that, but the issue comes then when I'm trying to compare the times vs my cutoff in my removeExpiredItems func.

I was trying to do something like:

Take the timestamps, change them to a string , then down when I'm going to make the comparison change the String to an Int but I get something like "This kind of conversion will always fail".

Any ideas here?

Comment: I think you should change the value to UInt64 before compare. let aTime = UInt64(self.postsArray[0])

Comment: for using AnyObject  typed Array for storing timeinterval values  you need use NSNumber to wrap values.

let arr:[AnyObject] = [NSNumber(double: 1.0)]

Comment: @AliKıran Ahhh okay I see. That makes more sense. Xcode was NOT liking what I was trying to do .

Thanks to you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let post = snapshot.value!["MinutesLeft"]
```

The type of `post` will be `AnyObject, (Optional<AnyObject>)` in this case.

You have store it as the data type you want. For example in this case you can store it as `NSTimeInterval`

```
 let post = snapshot.value!["MinutesLeft"] as! NSTimeInterval
```

And store it in an Array of `NSTimeInterval` as

```
var postsArray :[NSTimeInterval] =  []
```